# why the color of the label doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

After the page loads the color of the label *(which is "enter your name")* should change to red.But the color of the label remains the same.Why is this so ?

**SCRIPT**

```
window.onload = startScript;

function startScript() {
if( document.getElementById("text_field").value === "me") {
    var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    allTags.className = "inserter";
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inserter.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("inserter.css");
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#99FFFF">
<form>
<label>Enter your name<input type="text" id="text_field" value="me" />
</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.inserter {
color:#F00;
}
```

Now since the value is equal to `me` class name "inserter" is dynamically inserted to the label element and the color should appear to be red.

Why doesn't this happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to loop through `allTags`:

```
var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i = 0; i < allTags.length; i++) {
  allTags[i].className = 'inserter';
}
```

If you can though use jQuery, it makes life so much easier!

UPDATE to add jQuery equivalent of your code:

```
if ($('#text_field').val() === 'me') {
  $('label').addClass('inserter');
}
```

It's just so much tidier

Comment: yes it does ! But currently i am a beginner to JavaScript. I think learning javascript first will be a benefit before moving on to `jQuery` ?

Comment: Definitely. Eventually you'll get to the point like me where you've almost forgotten what real javascript looks like. These days `javascript == jQuery` for me!

Answer (score 4):

The `getElementsByTagName` method returns an array containing each of the DOM elements that match that tag. Calling `allTags.className = 'inserter'` assigns a value to the 'className' property of the array itself, not to each of the elements within that array. You'll need to iterate through it, and assign the className to each tag individually.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned **getElementsByTagName()** returns an array with elements but also you should add brackets to the first row where you call **startScript()** to identify it as a function.

This example works; http://jsfiddle.net/aQASU/

Answer (score 0):

Try this through jquery.

```
allTags.addClass("inserter");
```